# How to update from Paramiko 1.16.0 to 1.16.1 if there is no .deb package for it and pip install specific version doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-14.04, python-3.4, paramiko

I need to update paramiko 1.16.0 to 1.16.1 but I can't find a .deb package and pip3 install paramiko==1.16.1 gives an error.

I've already tried pip3 install --upgrade paramiko==1.16.1 and
I can't find a .deb package for 1.16.1 anywhere. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

this is the error I receive when trying to upgrade with pip3

```
berryhp@C001812114:~/clones/testcommander/tests$ pip3 install --upgrade paramiko==1.16.1
Downloading/unpacking paramiko==1.16.1
  Downloading paramiko-1.16.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (170kB): 170kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking ecdsa>=0.11 (from paramiko==1.16.1)
  Downloading ecdsa-0.13.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59kB): 59kB downloaded
Requirement already up-to-date: pycrypto!=2.4,>=2.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from paramiko==1.16.1)
Installing collected packages: paramiko, ecdsa
  Found existing installation: paramiko 1.16.0
    Not uninstalling paramiko at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, owned by OS
  Can't roll back paramiko; was not uninstalled
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 672, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 902, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 206, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 193, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destsubdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 237, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/paramiko-1.16.1.dist-info'

Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpd0xunwr_
```

Comment: Why would you want to update to Paramiko 1.16.1? Use the latest version!

Comment: I was told that I couldn't download a newer version than 1.16 and have it work on 14.04 but I just downloaded 2.4.2 and it seems to be working so I guess they were wrong.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Using some older versions might be the requirement.
For instance my customer checks and approves each package version (in a long process) and I often need to use old verions of libraries.

Comment: @gbajson Using **3 years** old version of **security** software is hardly an acceptable requirement.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - It depends on the customer. In Telco it's rather a common practice that no one cares about security and security is not a requirement at all. It's a bitter true, but true. Most of internal systems I installed or supported in last 20 years were never patched during their life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just updating to paramiko 2.4.2 by installing the .deb from http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/paramiko/python3-paramiko_2.4.2-0.1ubuntu1_all.deb